# Python loop index of key, value for-loop when using items()

Tags: python, dictionary

Im looping though a dictionary using

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
```

And I wondered if theres some pythonic way to also access the loop index / iteration number. Access the index while still maintaining access to the key value information.

```
for key, value, index in mydict.items():
```

its is because I need to detect the first time the loop runs. So inside I can have something like

```
if index != 1:
```

Comment: It is not as I want to preserve access to the dictionary key and values as well.

Comment: You know dictionaries aren't sorted, so your `index` isn't really an index, its just a running count of how many things you've done so far.

Comment: Yes Lego Stormtroopr, hence the "loop index / iteration number"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, like this

```
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    print index, key, value
```

The `enumerate` function gives the current index of the item and the actual item itself. In this case, the second value is actually a tuple of key and value. So, we explicitly group them as a tuple, during the unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the index to do something special on the first iteration, you could also use `.popitem()`

```
key, val = mydict.popitem()
...
for key, val in mydict.items()
    ...
```

this will remove the first `key, val` pair from `mydict` (but perhaps that's not an issue for you?)

Answer (score 0):

```
if mydict:
    iterdict = mydict.iteritems()

    firstkey, firstvalue = next(iterdict)
    # do something special with first item

    for key, value in iterdict:
        # do something with the rest
```